# Lotus Domino. Web Services. CXF. What is the package name for the CXF classes?

Tags: java, cxf, xpages, lotus-domino

I've [built and deployed a custom web services consumer in Java on Domino using the available CXF framework](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8SUKV5).

This is done via an XPage which is calling some Java code stored as Java design elements. It's all working perfectly. (Thanks again Stephan!)

Now I would like to implement logging programmatically to take a look at the SOAP requests/responses as [detailed here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/debugging-and-logging.html#DebuggingandLogging-LoggingMessages).

So I'm attempting to use the following:

**IMPORTS**

```
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor;
```

**Logging Interceptor Code**

```
CustomWebService customWebService = new CustomWebService(new URL(WSDL_URL));
CustomWebServiceSoap customWebServiceSoap = customWebService.getCustomWebServiceSoap();

CustomWebServiceSoap port = customWebService.getPort(customWebServiceSoap.getClass());

Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```

The problem is that Domino doesn't have any of the cxf classes available to import e.g. org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client etc.

Are they under a different package name? If so, which one? I had a look through the com.ibm.* packages but nothing seemed obvious. Plu type-ahead didn't show anything matching Client or ClientProxy.

Or do I need to import the relevant CXF jars to my NSF to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use CXF you need to include the JARs for sure.

But the Web Service Client functionality introduced in Stephan's article is not using CXF classes but JAX-WS classes (it just uses CXF *wsdl2java* but you could as well use the JAX-WS version of it). That is part of Java starting from version 6. I'm not sure if CXF is of any help when logging JAX-WS client and I think you need to look at logging JAX-WS instead of CXF.